# 3.3v and many Leds: LED brightness?

Tags: led, driver, 3.3v, teensy

I'm using a Teensy 3.0 which outputs 3.3v 100mA. I would like to connect many leds (probably 100…). Obviously I fear that the brightness of all the leds will be lower than I like to. I'm using the STP16CP05, a constant-current led driver.
Do you think it is possible to maybe connect 5v to the vss of the STP16CP05s (I have 5v available on my board) or will it cause problems with the Teensy?
Do you may have any other suggestions?

Also: Would the led brightness sink from each led to led or would each led have the same (low?) brightness?

Comment: How much current do you have available on the 5V and 3V3 rails?

Comment: .... and how much current (and at what forward voltage) does each LED require (demand)?

Comment: Table 2, page 3 of the pdf states Vdd between 3.3 and 5V (it also indicates the absolute range is between 3 and 7V) and one of the features (first page top) is it "can be driven by a 3v3 microcontroller" so its looking good.

Comment: the Teensy pinout says: 3.3v (100mA max). This a the leds I'm using (three wire bi color leds): http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/216/WP115VEGW-43783.pdf

Comment: Or the TLC5926 which isn't a low voltage one: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs677/slvs677.pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [STP16CP05 (Datasheet)](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00126634.pdf) is a constant current SINK, where the logic's voltage level and the led's voltage level are separate. Essentially, the outputs are npn transistors or n-channel mosfets controlled by the STP16CP05's logic.

Each STP16CP05 can be powered by 3.3v, for communication from a 3.3v micro, and will only use ~4.5mA of power from that 3.3v supply, for the logic side, when the constant current is set to 20mA with a 1k resistor. Uses 11mA when the constant current is set to 100mA Per Channel (1600mA per STP16CP05 max).

The LED side requires a Voltage that closely matches the LED's Forward Voltage (Or Multiple LED's Vf added up), with 0.3v to 1.5v left over (Lower is better, heat wise). You could power multiple leds on the same channel with a high enough Vl (Max 20v).

[image]

Since the Teensy 3.0 has a 3.3v regulator with a 120mA limit, with the Teensy itself using 20mA, that means you have <100mA free to use on that regulator.

The [LEDs (Datasheet)](http://www.tme.eu/de/Document/1c251eb05faa576a218d5867afb05d2d/l-115wegw-ca.pdf) you use are Common Anode BI-Color Leds, One Red typically 2.2v forward drop at 20mA, and One Green typically 2.4v at 20mA. As common Anode, the Positive side is tied together, preventing adding them in series with individual color control, so you can't simply use a higher voltage as would be ideal.

If you want to power a hundred leds (or 200 channels, 2 per led, 1 per color), at 20mA, that would be 200 x 20mA, 4 Amps of power needed. You would also need (200 channels / 16 bits or 12.5) 13 STP16CP05s, taking just 65mA of the 3.3v supply. You will not be able to do that from the Teensy's 3.3v supply. You will not be able to do that from a computer usb connection (Typically 500mA).

You will need a dedicated 3.3v supply, at least 4 amps. The STPs and the Tiny don't use much and can be powered from that supply, ignoring the on board regulator, but you would want to only give the leds 17mA , just to be on the safe side of not running the supply at absolute max (3.5A), and lets you expand a bit if needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0k837.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To illustrate, see the schematic I made above (only 3 leds/6 channels shown because it would be messy otherwise). Since you can't put the LEDs in series, a 3.3v or 3.0v supply would be best. A 1.2k~1.4k resistor would be best for REXT on each STP for ~17mA draw. A 0.1 uf or slightly bigger decoupling cap on each STP as well.

Note, Since the LEDs have a different forward voltage, there might be a slight difference in brightness, if you put both colors on the same STP. You could put 16 of the red side on one STP with a Rext of 1.1k and the 16 of the green side on another STP with a Rext of 1.2k or 1.3k, to even it out.

Last note, you can connect them how ever you want. Every odd output could be red, every even green, or half an STP red Half green, or one stp per color. Wiring is really up to you, you would then just adjust your code. 8 and 8 or 16 would be, imho best, simply because 8bits and 16bits are standard sizes in coding, and you wouldn't have to adjust for every other bit.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean I could connect it to my 3.3v teensy, but give it a different voltage like e.g. 12v? I actually connect 12v to my final board and regulate it to 5v for the teensy (which accepts 5v and regulates it to 3.3). --- I dont get VL. I thought I would only need to connect the leds to the OutX and a GND.

Comment: Ah or is it the way around? I connect the leds to a voltage and the constant current sink connects them to a GND (or not, if the led shouldn't lit)?

Comment: Yes. Vl is Voltage(Led). Max 20v. You connect the leds to the 12v (aka VL) and the STP's "output" pins. If you use 12v, you will need a few leds in series. At 2~2.2V Forward Voltage, that would be 5 in series. But you are using bi-color leds which make connecting them in series pretty difficult.

Comment: And yes, the constant current SINKS, connecting them to ground (through internal transistors/mosfets). When the outputs are off, the leds are left floating, so the leds are off. When the outputs are on, the leds are tied to ground and light up.

Comment: I could also connect the leds to 5v. This would eliminate the need for leds in series, right? Btw. Is there something the way around? Where I can connect all the leds to GND and a led chip outputs the voltage (which should be still independent to the voltage it gets controlled from)?

Comment: @Flocked No, because 5v - 2v is 3v. 5v - 2.3v is 2.7v. The STP can only handle 1.5 to 0.5v at the output. And it can only sink voltage, not source it. You would a different ic for that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused. Where did you find the information? If I look at the datasheed i see "Output voltage" max 20v. - And would this work? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5925.pdf

Comment: Or would the tlc5926 work? It isn´t low-power http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5926.pdf

Comment: Yes, I need bi color leds with 3 wires (so that I can run both color as the same time with same brightness as 1 color) and 3mm size. Hm :/

Comment: Thanks for taking all your time! I really appreciate it. I'm sorry, but I already had common anode leds, I just linked to the wrong ones. I have these: http://www.tme.eu/de/Document/1c251eb05faa576a218d5867afb05d2d/l-115wegw-ca.pdf And yes, my plan was to connect each cathode to the output (so 2 outputs per led). My big question regarding power still exists. How should I connect everything? VDD of the driver gets connected to 3.3v of the teensy. But what power should the leds get? 5v/12v available on my board or 3.3v of the teensy?

Comment: @Flocked I greatly expanded it based on your leds. Added a sample schematic and everything. You will need a 3.3v supply of at least 4 amps (Either dedicated, or cheaper way, a 12v 3A+ (36W) with a buck switching regulator board to 3.3v) based on 100 2 color leds that can't be put in series. But you will have individual control of every single one, as well as be able to provide 4 colors (off, red, green, r+g= yellow).

Comment: Wow thanks so much. You helped me a lot :) One last question: Why did you used a capacitor and connected the vcc of the drivers additionally to ground?

Comment: @Flocked those are decoupling capacitors. They help stabilize the vcc input to the ics. They should be very close to the vcc of the chips. Standard parts.